# Retry a failed job using Python Jenkins API

Tags: python, jenkins

I wanted to retry a failed build job using Python. I have used the API like,

```
build_job_info = server.get_job_info('my_job') 
['lastFailedBuild']['number']
```

to get the last failed build number. How can I use the API to retry the failed build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to retry a failed one. So here I build the job again with the same parameters like,

```
build_info = server.build_job('my_job')
```